# Site broken with "Call to undefined function entity_get_info()"

Tags: entities

I am working on a module that uses a custom entity built with eck. I got the white screen of death while making changes to a function. I completely commented the function I was working on when it started. But the white scren persists. /var/log/httpd/error_log reports "Call to undefined function entity_get_info()"

I can only avoid the error by disabling the entity module. (Then the site works normally.)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Weird stuff like this can be caused by APC misbehaving.  I would try disabling API in api.ini, restarting Apache, and see what happens.

Comment: I can't find a file called api.ini. I restarted apache with no effect.

Comment: Sorry, I meant apc.ini.  On CentOS, it is /etc/php.d/apc.ini  The settings may also be in the main /etc/php.ini

Comment: No apc.ini and I didn't see anything like "apc" in php.ini. What section would it be in? CentOS 6.5

Comment: You may not have it installed, then.  admin/reports/status/php will have an APC section if it is.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I dropped the database and started from zero - gotta keep moving :)